# How to pass querystring value in @Url.Action in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I passed a querystring value in _Layout.cshtml page

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shopping", "Index1", new { controller = "Shopping", UserID = "Admin" })</li>
```

**How to pass the value in the View Index1.cshtml page**

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","Shopping", new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"] })">
 <img alt="removeitem" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="17px" src="~/Images/remove.png" title="remove" />
 </a>
```

I am not getting the querystring value in my controller

```
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    string id = Request.QueryString["UserID"];
    int records = DeleteItem(id);
    if (records > 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shopping");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Can Not Delete");
        return View("Index");
    }
}

public int DeleteItem(string id)
{
    con.Open();          
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Cpecial_Shopping_Cart_tbl where [User ID]='" + id + "'", con);         
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an argument called id for your delete action method

```
Public ActionResult Delete(string id){
     //delete the Request.QueryString line
}
```